# How debug junit test executed by gradle connectedAndroidTest

Tags: android, junit, gradle

I execute my junit test by command`gradle connectedAndroidTest`
It's basically android integration test and I know exact class and line where is problem, but I need to debug it, because `gradle connectedAndroidTest --stacktrace` didn't help.
I'm using IDEA Community Edition 13.

How can I debug my test using breakpoint in affected class?

Answer (score 1):

Within IntelliJ, select the file that contains the integration test.  From the `Run` menu, select `Edit Configurations...` and create a new Gradle configuration.

In the `Tasks` box, that's where you enter the gradle task `connectedAndroidTest`.

In the script parameters, you want to limit it to your test, so it should be something like

`--tests "com.stackoverflow.android.services.MyFileNameTest.testMethodName"`

Once you click OK to save, that configuration will be available for both `Run` and `Debug`

Here's the IntelliJ doc for [debugging a Gradle task](http://bit.ly/1OY0dj7)

*** UPDATE ***
You might also consider triggering the task from command line and attaching the debugger.

[This thread](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-you-attach-a-debugger-to-gradle-so-that-i-can-debug-it-running-a-task/7526) talks about the flags you need for the command line debugging agent and [the IntelliJ docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/run-debug-configuration-remote.html) cover remote debugging.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get an Error running connectedAndroidTest: Unable to open debugger port (127.0.0.1:51178): java.net.SocketException "Socket closed"

Comment: Do you run into the same problem if you run `gradle connectedAndroidTest --tests "com.stackoverflow.android.services.MyFileNameTest.testMethodName"` from the command line?

Comment: no, because that error is an IntelliJ error, not a gradle one

Comment: @Keith Then you're running into a different problem.  The OP's question was just how to run the `connectedAndroidTest` task for a specific test in IntelliJ.  That's how you run the task.  It sounds like your task is running, but you're running into a different issues that's preventing the task from running as expected.

Comment: @Keith What happens if you have IntelliJ open, you run the test in IntelliJ to get the "Socket closed" error, then with IntelliJ still open, run `gradle connectedAndroidTest` from the command line?

Answer (score -1):

In android studio which is based on intellij 13, you can right click on the class/method name and then go to debug, that will run the test using the IDE's test runner in debug mode.